# Singleton Provider

Tags: c#, singleton

I've taken over a code base that is still very much in it's infancy, and stumbled across this class. I'm just wondering if it's actually worth it to have a `SingletonProvider`, and making use of `Lazy<T>` if it's just going to return the value straight away?

```
public static class SingletonProvider
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<object>> Instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<object>>();

    public static T GetSingleton<T>()
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return Instances.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), t => new Lazy<object>(() => Activator.CreateInstance(t), isThreadSafe: true)).Value as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense that singleton `T` must have a default parameterless constructor does it?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Another good point! I feel, if one is going to make a class a singleton, then do so explicitly.

Comment: Well `T` is not, by definition, a singleton; anyone and anything is free to instantiate it at will. This provider seems like a bad idea... indeed badly implemented ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that code base isn't sprinkled with calls to that `SingletonProvider`!

A "singleton provider", *conceptually*, makes no sense. This is highlighted by this generic type constraint:

```
where T : class, new()
```

By definition, `T` cannot be a singleton - it *must* expose a public, parameterless constructor to satisfy the type constraint!

I'm not sure what to call this *provider*, but it definitely needs a rename refactoring, to remove the confusing notion of "Singleton".

Consider this hypothetical client code:

```
var foo = SingletonProvider.GetSingleton<Something>();
```

And then, elsewhere:

```
var bar = SingletonProvider.GetSingleton<Something>();
```

What have we gained? `foo` is a reference to the same object as `bar`. But if `Something` *must* be a Singleton, then a much less surprising approach would be something like:

```
var foo = Something.GetInstance();
```

And then, there's no way to accidentally do this elsewhere:

```
var bar = new Something();
```

...and you keep your code coupled with *one* class instead of two.

---

I see what problem this class is trying to solve: it's not all that rare that an object must only ever exist in once instance.

The problem it's *creating* is that it's imposing way too heavy constraints on the type (`T`), and as a result this `Something` class must in turn be either tightly coupled with its own dependencies, or have them property-injected... which is unnecessary complexity.

I'd much rather code against an abstraction, say `ISomething`, and let the `Something` implementation decide how it wants to deal with its dependencies:

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;
    private readonly IBar _bar;

    public Something(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
    {
        _foo = foo;
        _bar = bar;
    }

    //...
}
```

If I have types that must depend on `ISomething`, I'll have them receive an instance in their constructor, have my favorite IoC container inject all its dependencies, and if I instruct my IoC container that whoever requires an `ISomething` implementation should always receive the same `Something` instance, I can do that without even implementing a Singleton - e.g. with Ninject it would look something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomething>().To<Something>().InSingletonScope();
```

The takeaway here is that the responsibility of *creating objects and managing object lifetimes* is the responsibility of the IoC container - not of some "SingletonProvider".

---

So why all this talk about IoC and dependency injection? Because good, SOLID object-oriented code strives for *low coupling* (and *high cohesion* too). By coding against abstractions, you effectively reduce coupling to concrete types to a minimum; by using this `SingletonProvider`, you're not only coupled with the `SingletonProvider` class, but *also* with the concrete implementation of whatever the type of `T` is.

That `SingletonProvider` seems like a good way to make testing very hard, for very little benefit. It forces your client code to depend on concrete types, which increases coupling.

---

As for the implementation itself, I agree with you - it makes no sense to use a `Lazy<T>` if you're going to retrieve its value in the very same instruction; that leaves you with your already-initialized `Lazy<T>` instance in the dictionary, so you might as well directly store the instance itself.